# Jquery this and selectors

Tags: jquery

How can you select using `this` the direct children of the element ?

Something like `$(this).find('p')` but for direct children.

Update : 
there is a difference between a direct children and a sibling.

Comment: I think you should read jQuery's API before asking this kind of things, this one is really easy to find searching a little

Comment: @jondavidjohn [who has since deleted his comment] `find` is not limited to only direct descendants; it searches the whole tree below the context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children):

`$(this).children('p')`

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).children('elementnode')`

Anytime you wrap a DOM element with `$` you have access to prototypal methods, and `children` is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

`>` searches the children of the given element.

```
$(this).find('> p');

$('> p', this);

$(this).children('p');
```